# How do I update/delete this app?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, applications

I have an app that looks like it tries to continuously install. It's been like that for weeks. I have free space, like 2GB. When I long press the icon, and try to delete it, it pops up a dialog asking me if I want to delete, but it doesn't delete. I can't even delete it from iTunes. It doesn't have an X on the icon like other apps do. I tried to click Update for the app and sync, but it doesn't work and the icon is still like that. When I just try to launch the app, it does nothing.

[image: imgur app]

iPhone 5, iOS 9.2.1, Windows 8.1, iTunes 12.3.3.17

Comment: is there a profile installed in your settings? it should be under Settings -> General -> Profiles & Device Management

Comment: @bret7600 There is, but how does that effect it?

Comment: A profile may force any app onto or off of the device, your workplace (if this is a work phone) may be preventing you from deleting some apps from the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned the phone off, on, and re-synched with iTunes and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings - General - Storage & iCloud Usage - Storage: Manage Storage. You can also delete apps from here.

Comment: I believe it was showing as `(null)`, but I forget now.